# Is Rspec needed and why is need?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i was following rails tutorial from http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ . I then came across chapter 3 : rspec gem and i got frustrated as my program couldn't get exactly the same thing as the tutorial. I followed every detail steps but still ended up couldn't solve the error. I then proceed with my own project and deal the problems later.

Now i'm curious whether do i need Rspec in my program ? I mean what is it for actually ? All i see in the tutorial was it's actually like a checker ? or guideline what u're suppose to do after this steps and next.

Comment: Rspec is a unit testing suite. It is not "required", but it is recommended to use it with your projects. Well written unit tests can help you quickly find bugs in your code by running it through a continuous integration environment before merging your code to the main branch.

Comment: ah ... ic ... So it's not really compulsory to have them ? Its optional right ? And 1 more question is about the gemfile. It seems that the tutorial had those gems called in different unit.( development,test n production) what are those and how do i differentiate them ? I meando they work seperately ? O.O ... because what i'm doing now is i declared my gemfile in 1 folder at thats all... without specifying the gem is for test unit/prod/development unit... i then see my results using localhost:3000/... n only debug

Comment: The `Gemfile` is used to define your project dependencies. Since your project will run in at least 3 different environments (Production, Development and Test), you can have different gems (plugins) for each environments. For example, Rspec should not be added in the Production environment since you should need to run your tests suites in production, only in development and test (while debugging / developing features).

Comment: Pierre : So how do i test the development and test ? I mean do they run seperately ? when i call localhost:3000 is this the production part ? @.@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About RSpec**

RSpec is a unit testing suite. It is not mandatory but having a test suite is highly recommended. A gem that will help you build tests for your projects in order to make sure that it is working properly. In this world where projects are getting bigger and bigger, you want to make sure that all the pieces of your products is working at any time.

For example, after weeks developing features, you might find yourself in a position where you need to refactor some of your code (bad smell code, to hard to maintain, etc...).

If you wrote tests (also called specs) right from the beginning, it will be much easier to refactor your code without worrying if your new written code breaks anything or not.

If you did not, well you could refactor your code anyway and take the risk that your product do not work correctly anymore, or you could first write specs and then refactor.

**About the Gemfile**

Regarding your second question about the Gemfile, a Gemfile is used to define your project dependencies. Since your project will run in at least 3 different environments (Production, Development and Test), you can have different gems (plugins) for each environments.

For example, RSpec should not be added in the Production environment since it will not be used in production, only while debugging / developing features (development and test mode).

When you do:

```
rails server
```

It's launching the Rails server in development mode by default (using the gems defined in development hook or without any hook at all)

If you want to run the Rails server in production you can do:

```
rails server -e production
```

Take the following gemfile for example:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# gem require for ALL mode (yes, rails is a gem)
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

group :production do
  # gems required only in production mode
end

group :test, :development do
  # gems required only in development AND test mode
end

group :development do
  # gems required only in development mode
end

group :test do
  # gems required only in test mode
end

# another gem required for all modes    
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

A great book to learn Rails http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

A great resource about gemfile http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html

Comment: oh ... now i understand those codes... Thanks for explaining to me =)

Comment: you welcome :) enjoy coding with rails !